# Can anyone please tell me how to play this in "La Campanella"?

Tags: piano, technique, practice, fingering

I can't play the grace notes. Either it gets out of sync or there is a noticeable delay. [image: La Campanella m. 14]

Answer (score 4):

**Fingering**

I recommend `1-2-3` for `Fx-G#-A#`. That works best for my hand, and it's also the fingering used by the following performers (whose hands are visible):

- [Rousseau](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H1Dvg2MxQn8)
- [Valentina Lisitsa](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MD6xMyuZls0)
- [Lang Lang](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cIxGUAnj46U)
- [Kassia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hf2MFBz4S_g)

(Helpful tip: on YouTube, you can use `,` and `.` to move frame by frame backward and forward, respectively.)

**Relaxation**

Tensing up when playing fast is a frequent problem. You might be tightening your hand to play the grace notes, or tightening your upper arm to move quickly to the high `D#`.

**Practice technique**

Play slowly. Play the first three notes, releasing the `A#` with a staccato "leap" to the high `D#`. *Your movement should make a single, smooth arc* (a parabola). If you find yourself adjusting your arm position in mid-air, or if you need to adjust your finger position as you approach the `D#`, then your direction of movement is not yet efficient enough to make the leap at speed.

When your movements draw a smooth curve, then slowly speed up.

Comment: Although I'd hesitate to argue about fingerings with the people @Aaron mentions... ! ... you could also try crossed-over 2-3-1, with your thumb already close to the A-sharp. This somewhat spreads out the difficulty... depending on your hands.